# Linux, having trouble adding user to second group

Tags: linux, group

Redhat Linux 5.10 (Tikanga)

I'm trying to add an existing user to a second group. The user is already part of the primary group called "prim" and the secondary group I want to add him to is "sec". I've tried these:

```
sudo usermod --append sec chuck # Got the syntax screen for usermod
sudo usermod -G prim -append sec chuck # Got the syntax screen again.
```

The man page for `usermod` says `--append GROUP` requires the `-G`, which I did. So, how do I add this user to a second group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
usermod -aG groupname username
```